# Can not export code style settings. JetBrains, Rider

Tags: ide, coding-style, editor, jetbrains-ide, rider

What I am trying to do is following:

1. Open up the project from which I want to export code style settings. Go to `File` -> `Export Settings`

[image]

2. Choose location where to save the settings and save them.
3. Open up the project to which I want apply exported setting and just import them through `File` menu.
4. Now JetBrains, Rider recommends to reopen the ide. I agree and reopen, but when ide opens up no code style changes are applied and I get the same warnings as before.

While exporting and importing the settings I made sure that all the checkboxes are checked. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Export/Import Settings` is about IDE general settings -- it has nothing to do with specific project settings. This can be used when you wish backup/restore your settings .. or copy them between computers etc.

Comment: Individual project settings are stored in `.idea` subfolders .. and you may copy most of the files between the projects (while project is **closed** in IDE, of course).

Comment: @LazyOne, do you mean to just `copy/paste` the files from `.idea` folder between different projects?

Comment: Correct. Works for PhpStorm .. so will work for Rider as well (as they both IDEA-based). Once again -- it depends on a file: you may copy code style/inspection profile/dictionaries/scopes/other shared stuff. BTW: *future new projects* -- the default settings for them can be set in `File | Default Settings...`

Comment: @LazyOne, I see nothing in the `.idea` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the exported JAR file, you will probably see that the XML files in the `codestyles/` directory don't contain any information (just tried it myself).

I suspect that this is related to this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15090

You might want to watch that bug report to see when it is resolved or whether there are any workarounds.